# TTCN to C conversion

Tags: c, ttcn

is there a open source TTCN tool which can convert TTCN script to C

Answer (score 3):

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.titan
This tool can help, it converts TTCN files to C++ so then you just have to pass to C

Edit: some more info: https://polarsys.org/wiki/images/9/95/TITAN_Datasheet_3.b-090914.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any substantial projects, but there is:

- [Yet Another TTCN Runner](http://code.google.com/p/yatr/)
- [T3DevKit](http://www.irisa.fr/tipi/wiki/doku.php/t3devkit) (which has a link to a `picottcn` project)